# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown flickering / not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I used this [FlexStart Boostrap Template](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/FlexStart/) in a project but I noticed a problem in the Dropdown on the navbar. The menu and submenu are flickering when I hover the mouse on it. Spend much time but can't solve it. Could you note why this isn't working?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the animation that plays when exiting the navigation menu. The menu moves downward and fades out. However, since your mouse is in the way, it triggers the fade-in and move-up animation.

In your example, notice the flickering only occurs when the menu interacts with the cursor during the animation.

[image: Menu flickering like a light bulb.]

Assuming your code is exactly the same, the animation is triggered by the `:hover` pseudo selector for the `.navbar .dropdown ul` class.

Remove both `top` properties from the following selectors `.navbar .dropdown:hover > ul` and `.navbar .dropdown ul`.

```
.navbar .dropdown:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%; /* Delete This */
    visibility: visible;
}

.navbar .dropdown ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    top: 100%; /* Delete This */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, because you are NO longer hovering over the menu link itself, you're getting out of the link and hovering over the 10px bottom padding of the `.navbar .dropdown ul`.

Here's an image to explain those `padding: 10px 0` on `.navbar .dropdown ul` and why the menu disappear:

[image]

When you hover over the green area (10px top and 10px bottom of the ul), it means you aren't hovering over the link.

You can simply delete that padding, and it won't flicker anymore.